# How do I use the PDFViewer.jar library in android?

Tags: java, android, pdf-reader, pdf-viewer

I am trying to use the [`PDFViewer.jar` library](https://code.google.com/p/apv/) to read pdf into my application android pdf reader.

I wonder how to use to read pdf form the resources in asset folder.
it required to "PATH TO PDF GOES HERE"

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourPdfViewerActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, "PATH TO PDF GOES HERE");
startActivity(intent);`
```

Comment: Does PDFViewer has search option? Or highlight? (is it something like MuPDF?)

Answer (score 0):

It's explaining quite good and works for me.

http://upadhyayjiteshandroid.blogspot.com/2013/03/android-pdf-viewer-application.html?showComment=1397014240605#c4120910608580621305

Answer (score 0):

Yes path is required

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourPdfViewerActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, "file:///android_asset/pdf_name.pdf");
             startActivity(intent);
```